# Quintic polynomial solution by Jacobi Theta function.

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Does someone have a good and rigorous reference for the solution of quintic ploynomial equation with Jacobi Theta function, in English?

Mathworld and Wikipedia don't give a good English reference, at least from what I skimmed over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you ask about solution to high degree polynomials? The following are some reference:

- Umemura H. (2007) Resolution of algebraic equations by theta constants. In: Tata Lectures on Theta II. Modern Birkhäuser Classics. Birkhäuser, Boston, MA. doi:[10.1007/978-0-8176-4578-6_18](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4578-6_18)
- L. Bers, *Uniformization, Moduli, and Kleinian Groups*, Bulletin of London Math. Soc. **4** (1972) 257-300,  doi:[10.1112/blms/4.3.257](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/4.3.257)
- F. Klein, *Lectures on the icosahedron*, 2nd edition, Dover, 1956; [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059413439)
- Prasolov and Solovyev, *Elliptic functions and elliptic integrals*,
  Translations of Mathematical Monographs 1997. [AMS bookstore](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-170)
- Richard J. Drociuk, *On the Complete Solution to the Most General Fifth Degree Polynomial* https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005026

Comment: Let me just comment that the Drociuk paper writes the solution in terms of a special value of a hypergeometric function, which is essentially a [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical). It doesn't claim to break the Abel–Ruffini theorem, despite the alarm bells the appearance (and some of the prose) of the preprint might raise.

Answer (score 15):

There's also a very nice, modern exposition by Mark L. Green:  *On the analytic solution of the equation of fifth degree*, Compositio Mathematica **37** (1978), 233–241.  A pdf of the paper is available online:  http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1978__37_3_233_0